# Chapter Title adjusting with koma-script

Tags: sectioning, koma-script, titlesec

The following minimal working example is not giving me the desired results. I would like to keep the chapter titles layout, but without using the `titlesec` package. The `titlesec` package is interfering with the option `headings=optiontotoc`. This becomes visible in the table of contents by showing empty entries instead of leaving them away.

Unfortunately my koma-script skills are strongly limited. Does anybody have an idea how to create the desired chapter titles layout with code only?

I also tried the `loadonly` option provided by the titlesec package, which is producing errors.

Here is the minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,numbers=noenddot,headings=optiontotoc]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\renewcommand{\sffamily}{\rmfamily}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\usekomafont{chapter}\bfseries\raggedleft}{\vspace{-3em} \textsc{Kapitel} \thechapter \vspace{1.5em}}{.5 em}{\vspace{-1em} \titlerule  \vspace{.5em}}[\vspace{.5em} \titlerule]

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter}

\section{Section}  
Hier folgt dann der Text

\subsection{Subsection}  
Hier folgt dann der Text

\subsection{Subsection 2}  
Hier folgt dann der Text

\chapter[]{Nullchapter}
Und hier folgt dann der Text

\section[]{Nullsection} 
Und hier folgt dann der Text

\subsection[]{Nullsubsection} 
Und hier folgt dann der Text

\end{document}
```

Desired Chapter Title Layout:

[image: chapter title]

Empty Entries in TOC because of the titlesec package:
[image: toc]

Comment: I believe, you missed `\chapter*{Title}`, `\section*{Title}`  and `\subsection*{Title}` instead of `\chapter[]{Nullchapter}` etc.

Comment: @Christian Thanks for your reply. I am aware of the starred versions, but i need numbering.

Comment: The German manual of KOMA classes (4th edition, on page 110) explicitly states that the section formatting mechanism works only if there is no other package doing that.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Unfortunately, I don't have access to the mentioned manual. But if understand you correctly, that is part of the reason why i would like to get rid of the `titlesec` package and only use koma-script commands instead. Do you know a way to get the posted chapter title style with koma-script code?

Comment: There is a `\chapterformat` command within KOMA classes, that sets up the style how the chapter title is formatted. Unfortunately, I am not an expert with KOMA :-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a working solution through:
http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&p=53313. The command `@makechapterhead` is used for all numbered titles and `@makeschapterhead` for all unnumbered titles.

A full working minimal example looks like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt,numbers=noenddot,headings=optiontotoc,chapterprefix]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\renewcommand{\sffamily}{\rmfamily}

\makeatletter

\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
    \vspace*{10\p@}%
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedleft \reset@font
        \huge \scshape \@chapapp{}  \thechapter\vspace*{-15\p@}
        \par\nobreak
        \interlinepenalty\@M\hrulefill\newline\vspace*{-5\p@}
        \huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
        \vspace*{-8\p@}%
        \hrulefill
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 30\p@
}}

\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
    \vspace*{4\p@}%
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedleft \reset@font
        \scshape
        \interlinepenalty\@M\hrulefill\newline\vspace*{-5\p@}
        \huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
        \vspace*{-8\p@}%
        \hrulefill
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 30\p@
}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\chapter{Chapter}

\section{Section}  
Hier folgt dann der Text

\subsection{Subsection}  
Hier folgt dann der Text

\subsection{Subsection 2}  
Hier folgt dann der Text

\chapter[]{Nullchapter}
Und hier folgt dann der Text

\section[]{Nullsection 2} 
Und hier folgt dann der Text

\subsection[]{Nullsubsection} 
Und hier folgt dann der Text

\end{document}
```

Thank you @ChristianHupfer for all your suggestions and patience.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to omit the entry into `\tableofcontents`, you should use the **starred** versions of the sectioning commands, such as `\chapter*`, `\section*` etc. This however prevents numbering of the sections.

```
\documentclass[11pt,numbers=noenddot,headings=optiontotoc]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\renewcommand{\sffamily}{\rmfamily}



\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\usekomafont{chapter}\bfseries\raggedleft}{\vspace{-3em} \textsc{Kapitel} \thechapter \vspace{1.5em}}{.5 em}{\vspace{-1em} \titlerule  \vspace{.5em}}[\vspace{.5em} \titlerule]

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter}

\section{Section}  
Hier folgt dann der Text

\subsection{Subsection}  
Hier folgt dann der Text

\subsection{Subsection 2}  
Hier folgt dann der Text

\chapter*{Nullchapter}
Und hier folgt dann der Text

\section*{Nullsection} 
Und hier folgt dann der Text

\subsection*{Nullsubsection} 
Und hier folgt dann der Text

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit**

Based on millo's solution, just as an extension:

```
\documentclass[11pt,numbers=noenddot,headings=optiontotoc,chapterprefix]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\renewcommand{\sffamily}{\rmfamily}

\setkomafont{chapter}{\raggedleft\huge}

\let\origchapapp\chapapp
\renewcommand{\chapapp}{\textsc{\origchapapp}}  % or \scshape{\origchapapp}

\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vskip-10pt}
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
    \raggedleft
    \chapapp\enskip\thechapter\\
    \hrulefill\\[-9pt]
}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadendvskip}{%
    \vspace{-12pt}\noindent{\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}\Huge\hrulefill\par}
    \vspace{\baselineskip}
}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter}

\section{Section}  
Hier folgt dann der Text

\subsection{Subsection}  
Hier folgt dann der Text

\subsection{Subsection 2}  
Hier folgt dann der Text

\chapter[]{Nullchapter}
Und hier folgt dann der Text

\section[]{Nullsection} 
Und hier folgt dann der Text

\subsection[]{Nullsubsection} 
Und hier folgt dann der Text


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I do need the numbering though. My thesis includes two table of contents. One for the content of the main part and an additional one for the appendix. For this reason i need numbered sections and subsections without entries in the toc-file.

Comment: @millo: I suspected that ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @ChristianHupfer for the hint with the `\chapterformat` command. I found a solution under the the link: http://www.komascript.de/chapterwithlines. With some editing i managed to come up with the following solution:

```
\documentclass[11pt,numbers=noenddot,headings=optiontotoc,chapterprefix]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\renewcommand{\sffamily}{\rmfamily}

\setkomafont{chapter}{\raggedleft\huge}

\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vskip-10pt}
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
    \raggedleft
    \chapapp\enskip\thechapter\\
    \hrulefill\\[-9pt]
}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadendvskip}{%
    \vspace{-12pt}\noindent{\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}\Huge\hrulefill\par}
    \vspace{\baselineskip}
}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter}

\section{Section}  
Hier folgt dann der Text

\subsection{Subsection}  
Hier folgt dann der Text

\subsection{Subsection 2}  
Hier folgt dann der Text

\chapter[]{Nullchapter}
Und hier folgt dann der Text

\section[]{Nullsection} 
Und hier folgt dann der Text

\subsection[]{Nullsubsection} 
Und hier folgt dann der Text


\end{document}
```

Unfortunately I am facing still two problems:

- The titles of the toc, list of tables, list of figures and appendix are behaving differently. It makes sense, that these titles do not recall the `\chapapp`command and show "Kapitel X" above "Inhaltsverzeichnis", but I would still like the `hrule`above them and similar spacing.
- I am not able to find a command that produces small caps for `\chapapp`. `\scshape`and `\textsc{}`did not work like I hoped. Can somebody come up with a workaround?

---

Chapter titles generated with the `titlesec` package:
[image: Inhaltsverzeichnis]

and

[image: Kapitel 1]

---

Chapter titles generated with code only:
[image: Inhaltsverzeichnis]

and

[image: Kapitel 1]

Comment: I added a suggestion about `\chappapp`, perhaps it works, but I have no solution about that line above `Inhaltsverzeichnis`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Your suggestion worked just fine. I found a way to input that extra line with the following command: `\BeforeTOCHead[toc]{%
 \cleardoublepage
 \let\clearpage\relax
 \noindent
 \hrulefill\\[7pt]
}`
This is not a good solution though, because this has to be done for every unnumbered title. I found another solution which I will share as a full answer.