# KOMA-Script:: interference between T1 fontenc and chapterformat

Tags: koma-script, font-encodings

I do no manage to obtain using pdflatex bold font for Chapter Name, prefix and number when `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` is loaded. The rendering is changing due to this package and the command `\bfseries` has no effect.

**with the T1 fontenc package:**
[image: with fontenc]

**without the T1 fontenc package:**
[image: without fontenc]

I found following related topics on the forum but was not able to find a solution to my issue. I would be very greatful for your help.

[Chapter Title adjusting with koma-script](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173389/chapter-title-adjusting-with-koma-script)
[CM fonts with T1 fontenc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11246/cm-fonts-with-t1-fontenc)
[Curious interaction between KOMA, fontenc and hyperref when using hidden glossary entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31835/curious-interaction-between-koma-fontenc-and-hyperref-when-using-hidden-glossar)

Note: I want to use only KOMA-Script command because of the known incompatibilities between `titlesec` package and `scrbook` documentclass.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,a4paper, headings=twolinechapter]{scrbook}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just to generate text for the example

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8, latin1]{inputenc}


% the chapter format:
\KOMAoption{chapterprefix}{true}

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
\raggedright%
\mbox{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}%
\scalebox{2.5}{\bfseries\color{gray}\thechapter\autodot}}\\}

\renewcommand*{\chapterheadendvskip}{%
\vspace{-12pt}\noindent{\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}\Huge\hrulefill\par}%
\vspace{\baselineskip}
}

\addtokomafont{chapter}{\raggedleft\Huge\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Title of the First Chapter}
\section{Title of the Section}
\subsection{Title of the Subsection}
\lipsum[1-2]
\chapter{Title of the second Chapter}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Add `\usepackage{lmodern}`. Unrelated, but important: give `inputenc` just one option; either `utf8` or `latin1`, according to your file's encoding.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reponses. Both solutions are working fine. Because I am not able to understand the second solution, I will prefer the use of the lmodern package even if no full documentation is available. I hope I do not produce new trouble somewhere else using this package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are both using bold but the T1 font is available in more design sizes so is considerably thinner at large size, the OT1 font is only available in 10pt and gets scaled.

You can force the T1 font to do the same, just using the 10pt scaled by adding

```
\makeatletter\input{t1cmss.fd}\makeatother
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{cmss}{bx}{n}%
  {<5><6><7><8><9><10->ecsx1000}{}
```

to the preamble.

Comment: Why not `{<->ecsx1000}`?

Comment: @egreg because I started to copy the OT1 fd file exactly but changed my mind half way through.

Answer (score 4):

The font is indeed bold, as the following test file shows

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand{\test}[1]{%
  normal: {#1test} --- bold: {#1\bfseries test}\par\medskip
}

\begin{document}
\sffamily

\test{\normalsize}
\test{\large}
\test{\Large}
\test{\LARGE}
\test{\huge}
\test{\Huge}

\fontencoding{OT1}\selectfont

\test{\normalsize}
\test{\large}
\test{\Large}
\test{\LARGE}
\test{\huge}
\test{\Huge}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see in the top half, the difference in weight is sensible between medium weight and boldface.

Typographically speaking, the bottom half is wrong, because the font scales linearly, becoming too much heavy at large sizes.

The Latin Modern fonts have the same defect as the Computer Modern, in that the largest optical size available is 17pt, while the European Modern fonts (used by default with T1 encoding) have more optical sizes available.

You get a much better result with the European Modern fonts; load the `type1ec` package that enables all the optical sizes with minimum amount of scaling for having every size available.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,a4paper, headings=twolinechapter]{scrbook}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just to generate text for the example

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{type1ec}

% the chapter format:
\KOMAoption{chapterprefix}{true}

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
\raggedright%
\mbox{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}%
\scalebox{2.5}{\bfseries\color{gray}\thechapter\autodot}}\\}

\renewcommand*{\chapterheadendvskip}{%
\vspace{-12pt}\noindent{\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}\Huge\hrulefill\par}%
\vspace{\baselineskip}
}

\addtokomafont{chapter}{\raggedleft\Huge\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Title of the First Chapter}
\section{Title of the Section}
\subsection{Title of the Subsection}
\lipsum[1-2]
\chapter{Title of the second Chapter}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Don't trust low resolution displays, look at the printed output or at a big magnification, staying far from the screen. Sans serif is already blacker than serif, it shouldn't be *too* heavy.