# How to adjust line spacing in wrapped chapter lines with KOMA-script?

Tags: sectioning, chapters, koma-script, line-spacing

I'm using `scrbook`. Some chapter titles are long and wrap, some of those even twice. When it goes on the third line, the spacing is different than that between the first and second lines. Looks terribly annoying (sorry for the lousy screenshot):

[image: ivanScrbookChaptertitle]

I've no idea why this happens, and I can't fix it.

There's substantial "literature" here on TeX.SE on formatting titles. The closest it gets to is the very nice discussion in [Control line spacing of section headings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/182874/12934), but it uses `titlesec`, so not an option. I tried to redefine `\chapterformat`, doesn't help:

```
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{%
\thechapter}{1em}{\setstretch{0.1}}
```

I tried to apply the two solutions in [Changing the linespacing of headings independently from the rest of the text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43899/12934). The one with the `\setstretch` in the mandatory argument just scales what there is. The other doesn't have any effect. The best thing that worked is `looseness=-1`, but it breakes "syntactic" in two.

EDIT: All apologies, here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,headings=optiontohead,version=last,openany]{scrbook}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}\date{}
\usepackage{suffix}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{}%prevent rewriting \markright 
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{}%prevent rewriting \markright 
\newcommand{\chapterauthor}[1]{\authortoc{#1}\printchapterauthor{#1}\markright{#1}}% setting \markright to author

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\printchapterauthor}[1]{%
 {\parindent0pt\vspace*{-10pt}%
 \linespread{1.1}\large\scshape#1%
 \par\nobreak\vspace*{30pt}}
 \@afterheading%
}
\newcommand{\authortoc}[1]{%
 \addtocontents{toc}{\vskip-10pt}%
 \addtocontents{toc}{%
 \protect\contentsline{chapter}%
 {\hskip1.3em\mdseries\scshape\protect\scriptsize#1}{}{}}
 \addtocontents{toc}{\vskip5pt}%
}
\makeatother
%% chapter formatting 
%% based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/173857/12934
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@chapapp}{}% remove the word `chapter'
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
  \linespread{2.5}\chapappifchapterprefix{\ }\thechapter\autodot\enskip}

\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
\vspace*{10\p@}%
{\parindent \z@ \raggedleft \reset@font
    \Huge \sffamily \@chapapp{}  \thechapter\vspace*{-15\p@}
    \par\nobreak
    \interlinepenalty\@M\hrulefill\newline\vspace*{-5\p@}
    \LARGE \sffamily #1\par\nobreak
    \vspace*{-8\p@}%
    \hrulefill
    \par\nobreak
    \vskip 30\p@
}}

\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
\vspace*{4\p@}%
{\parindent \z@ \raggedleft \reset@font
    \sffamily
    \interlinepenalty\@M\hrulefill\newline\vspace*{-5\p@}
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vspace*{-8\p@}%
    \hrulefill
    \par\nobreak
    \vskip 30\p@
}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{The walzing wombat went to the lazy lizard to get to the
dixie dancing ducks to have a meal of beloved bananas}
\kant[2]
\end{document}
```

I think now that the custom formatting is triggering it somehow...

Comment: Using titlesec with KOMA is never a good idea :-(

Comment: No! That's why I'm not using it :-)

Comment: Certainly the preamble (and a small document body) matters. Do you really believe one can analyze the behaviour without some code? Without knowing how you implemented the lines?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Mea culpa.

Comment: Replace the `\newline\vspace*{-5\p@}` by `\\[-5pt]`. `\vspace` inside a paragraph is inserted after the current line (and so the `\vspace{-5pt}` makes the space between your first two lines smaller). Btw: With your redefinitions you are completly overwriting the KOMA commands.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, this totally works. Thank you! And I promise I will be more sensible in my future questions :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a lack of the actual code, i cannot really tell why this spacing is introduced, but here a solution using KOMA-only methods.

[image: ivanKOMAChapterTitle]

```
\documentclass[english]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\KOMAoption{chapterprefix}{true}
\renewcommand*\raggedchapter{\raggedleft}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\large}
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{\thechapter\autodot\IfUsePrefixLine{}{\enskip}}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=0pt]{chapter}
\renewcommand{\chapterheadmidvskip}{%
    \par\nobreak\vskip -.1cm {\rule{.4\textwidth}{.5pt}}\par%
}
\renewcommand{\chapterheadendvskip}{%
    \begingroup
    \raggedchapter
    \rule{0.9\textwidth}{.5pt}\par%
\vspace*{\baselineskip}%
\endgroup
}

\usepackage{geometry}% Just for this test
\geometry{ margin=7cm }
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\chapter{The walzing wombat went to the lazy lizard to get to the
dixie dancing ducks to have a meal of beloved bananas}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

With a bit of tweaking, we get this:

[image: ivanKomaChaptertitleMod]

```
\documentclass[english]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{libertine}

\KOMAoption{chapterprefix}{true}
\renewcommand*\raggedchapter{\raggedleft}
\setkomafont{chapter}{\normalfont\large\sffamily}
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{\thechapter\autodot\IfUsePrefixLine{}{\enskip}}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=0pt]{chapter}
\renewcommand{\chapterheadmidvskip}{%
    \par\nobreak\vspace{\baselineskip}{\rule[.7\baselineskip]{.4\textwidth}{.4pt}}\par%
}
\renewcommand{\chapterheadendvskip}{%
\begingroup%
\raggedchapter%
\rule{\textwidth}{.5pt}\par%
\vspace*{\baselineskip}%
\endgroup%
}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{ margin=6.9cm }
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\chapter{The walzing wombat went to the lazy lizard to get to the
dixie dancing ducks to get some of their beloved bananabread}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Elke, siehst du das `raggedleft` im endvskip-Teil? Die `raggedchapter` Gruppe wird schon vorher geschlossen. Ist jetzt die Frage, sollte das mit in der ragged-Gruppe enthalten sein? Früher zumindest wurde in der Doku die Möglichkeit der Nutzung von Nicht-Space erwähnt.

Comment: Maybe  `\raggedchapter` instead `\raggedleft` is better?  And you could use `\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{\thechapter\autodot\IfUsePrefixLine{}{\enskip}}` and `\renewcommand*{\chapterheadmidvskip}{%
    \par\nobreak\vspace*{-\parskip}\vspace*{-.6\baselineskip}%
    \rule{0.4\textwidth}{.5pt}\par\nobreak\vskip.4\baselineskip%
}` Wegen der ragged Gruppe kann ich ihn nach seinem Urlaub fragen.

Comment: Alas, that doesn't help. I'll post my code in a minute.

Comment: Why `\raggedleft` to align a simple rule? Why not `\hfill`?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Esdd is right, `raggedchapter` would be more suited, in case the OP later decides to set this to raggedright or centered.

Comment: @esdd I was reusing code from the other answer ;-)

Comment: @IvanKapitonov How is my solution supposed to work? You are setting chapterhead yourself. This wouldn't even use my solution.

Comment: @Johannes_B: You mean, because of redefinitions?

Comment: You are defining `@@makechapterhead` and completely thowing a stick in the KOMA-machine. Try out my code as it is, it should work just fine. A few adjustments need to be made, considering the spacing and maybe a lighter font shape.

Comment: Actually touching the `@` stuff should be a warning sign, the `makeatletter` is a *switch to expert-mode* command, and hence should be dealt with in a sensible way.

Comment: @Johannes_B: That was stuff borrowed from elsewhere, -- but I take your point completely, it doesn't mean I shouldn't care about what I declare. And yes, your solution works, I'll study and tweak it.

Comment: @esdd Do you think it would be a good idea to put the chaptertitle (maybe even the prefix) in a box of a given width? I initially had the lower rule to a width of `.9\textwidth`. Consider 70% and the text would surely extend the rule making it even more ugly.